# Not able to alter cassandra db from bigint to text

Tags: cassandra, alter

I have column toor_0_sup with the bigint in cassandra db I want to change datatype to text.
How I can do that??
As we know for cassandra we cant change datatype from bigint to text.
If any solution for that will help me.

Tried to alter table but not working.

Answer (score 0):

By this thread discussion Altering column types is no longer supported.

REF: https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/314933/how-do-we-handle-alter-table-column-type-in-cassandra-in-actual-scenarios

Possible approach:

- unload the table data
- drop the table
- create the table with structure
- load the data